# HttpStatusCodeResult namespace not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Namespace is not recognized in Class Library project (EventService.cs)
but when I use it in Controller (MVC project)  it works fine and adds assembly properly:

```
 using System.Net;
```

Here is code for `EventService.cs` (Class Library Project that serves as interface for Controller)

```
public Event GetEventByID(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var @event = (from u in db.Event
                  where u.EventID == id
                  select u).FirstOrDefault();
    if (@event == null)
    {   
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return @event;
}
```

I've already tried deleting bin and obj folder in all projects and rebuild - no luck.Same code works ok in MVC projects.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding a reference to the `System.Net` dll to the library?

Comment: They are methods of `Controller` class (and need to go in you controller methods, not your class)

Comment: And they derive from `ActionResult` so even if you added the correct namespace, your code would throw an exception because your method is returning `Event`, not `ActionResult`

Comment: Start by changing the method to `public Event GetEventByID(int id)` (why in the world would you be able to pass `null` to a the method when that would cause it to fail. And then in your controller, check if the ID passed to the method is `null`,in which case you return use `new HttpNotFoundResult();` (you don't even call the method) and then after calling the method, if the return value is `null`, then `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);`

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke. Sorry, I'm newb.

Comment: Anyways this is service class not controller. Controller calls methods from here. I thought everything could be done here, testing and all and than passed to controller. ... I get it  HttpStatusCodeResult is MVC related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **HttpStatusCodeResult** is part of  **System.Web.Mvc** namespace. You will only get the reference if you have added mvc in your project.

Here you can find more details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.118).aspx